How to reuse script from Jenkins in GitHub Actions
I am migrating my code from Jenkins to GitHub Actions. My code in Jenkins is already in Production.
What does my pipeline do?

Reads Config.json file that is on GitHub.

In the Script, it initializes all variables, arrays, objects based on the values from Config.json.

Fires series of cURL commands based on the conditions.


What I intend to do?
Instead of reinventing the wheel for the GitHub Actions, I want to reuse the script {} code from Jenkins in the GitHub Actions by executing script.groovy from migrateToGitHubActions.yaml.
script.groovy has the exact code of script {} from Jenkins pipeline.
From my Jenkins:
    pipeline{
    agent any
    
    stages{
        stage('Start'){
            steps{
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
        stage('Clone Repo'){
            steps{
                git credentialsId: 'githubapp', url: 'https://github.com/configurations.git', branch: "${env}"
            }
        }
        stage('Configure'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh 'cat Config.json'
                    def configs = readJSON(file: 'Config.json')
                    def totalBundles = configs.bundles.size()
                    println "Total Array Size =" + totalBundles
                    def productName = new Object[totalBundles]
                    ....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Config.json:
    {
    "bundles":
    [
        {
            "product":{
                "name" : "Product1",
                "proxies" : ["'Proxy1', 'Proxy2'"],
                "attributes" : [{"name":"Test1","value":"abc"}]
            },
            "app":{
                "name":"App1",
                "attributes": [{"name": "attribute1","value": "null"}],
                "developer": "rohit@example.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "product":{
                "name" : "Product2",
                "proxies" : ["'Proxy1', 'Proxy2'"],
                "attributes" : [{"name":"Test2","value":"xyz"}]
            },
            "app":{
                "name":"App1",
                "attributes": [{"name": "attribute2","value": "null"}],
                "developer": "guifalourd@example.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}

My GitHub Actions migrateToGitHubActions.yaml:
name: Config

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [abc]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: List files (Start)
        run: |
            ls

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Install Groovy
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y groovy
      - name: Run Groovy script
        run: groovy script.groovy

script.groovy:
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

println "*** Before Read ***"

// Reading JSON from file
def jsonFile = new File('AppsProductsConfig.json')
def configs = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)

println "configs = $configs"
println "*** After Read ***"

def totalBundles = configs.bundles.size()
println "Total Array Size = $totalBundles"

// Initialization of arrays
def productName = new String[totalBundles]
def developer = new String[totalBundles]
def firstName = new String[totalBundles]
def lastName = new String[totalBundles]
def userName = new String[totalBundles]
def approvalType = new String[totalBundles]
def productAttributeName = new String[totalBundles]
def productAttributeValue = new String[totalBundles]
def displayName = new String[totalBundles]
def environments = new String[totalBundles]
def proxies = new Object[totalBundles][]
def appName = new String[totalBundles]
def appAttributeName = new String[totalBundles]
def appAttributeValue = new String[totalBundles]
def host = "example.com"
def USER = System.getenv('USER')

println "*** After Initialisation Read ***"

// Extract and Store Values
println "**** Read Variables ***"
for (int i = 0; i < totalBundles; i++) {
    def bundle = configs.bundles[i]

    // Products
    productName[i] = bundle.product.name
    approvalType[i] = "auto"
    productAttributeName[i] = bundle.product.attributes[0].name
    productAttributeValue[i] = bundle.product.attributes[0].value
    displayName[i] = bundle.product.name
    environments[i] = System.getenv('env') // Assuming 'env' is an environment variable
    proxies[i] = bundle.product.proxies

    // Developer
    developer[i] = bundle.app.developer
    firstName[i] = developer[i].takeWhile { it != '.' }
    def start = developer[i].indexOf(".") + 1
    def end = developer[i].indexOf("@")
    lastName[i] = developer[i].substring(start, end).replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "")
    userName[i] = developer[i].takeWhile { it != '@' }

    // Apps
    appName[i] = bundle.app.name
    appAttributeName[i] = bundle.app.attributes[0].name
    appAttributeValue[i] = bundle.app.attributes[0].value

    println "*** Print Apps & Products ***"
    println "Product Name = $productName[i]"
    println "App Name = $appName[i]"
    println "Approval Type = $approvalType[i]"
    println "Product Attributes Name = $productAttributeName[i]"
    println "Product Attributes Value = $productAttributeValue[i]"
    println "Display Name = $displayName[i]"
    println "Environments = $environments[i]"
    println "Proxies = ${proxies[i]}"
    println "Developer = $developer[i]"
    println "App Attributes Name = $appAttributeName[i]"
    println "App Attributes Value = $appAttributeValue[i]"
}

for (int i = 0; i < totalBundles; i++) {
    def productBody = """{
        "approvalType": "${approvalType[i]}",
        "attributes": [{"name": "${productAttributeName[i]}", "value": "${productAttributeValue[i]}"}],
        "displayName": "${displayName[i]}",
        "environments": ["${environments[i]}"],
        "name": "${productName[i]}",
        "proxies": ${proxies[i]}
    }"""
    println "Product Body = $productBody"

    def developerBody = """{
        "email": "${developer[i]}",
        "firstName": "${firstName[i]}",
        "lastName": "${lastName[i]}",
        "userName": "${userName[i]}"
    }"""
    println "Developer Body = $developerBody"

    def appBody = """{
        "name": "${appName[i]}",
        "apiProducts": ["${productName[i]}"],
        "attributes": [{"name": "${appAttributeName[i]}", "value": "${appAttributeValue[i]}"}],
        "keyExpiresIn": "31536000000"
    }"""
    println "App Body = $appBody"

    // Products
    def createProductResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request POST https://${host}/apiproducts", returnStdout: true).trim()
    println "$createProductResponse"

    if (createProductResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** Product ${productName[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createProductResponse.contains('409')) {
        def updateProductResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request PUT https://${host}/apiproducts/${productName[i]}", returnStdout: true).trim()
        println "$updateProductResponse"
        if (updateProductResponse.contains('200')) {
            println "*** Product ${productName[i]} updated successfully ***"
        } else {
            error "Failed to update ${productName[i]} with $updateProductResponse"
        }
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${productName[i]} with $createProductResponse"
    }

    // Developers
    def createDeveloperResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$developerBody' --request POST https://${host}/developers", returnStdout: true).trim()
    println "$createDeveloperResponse"

    if (createDeveloperResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** Developer ${developer[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createDeveloperResponse.contains('409')) {
        println "*** Developer already exists: $createDeveloperResponse ***"
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${developer[i]} with $createDeveloperResponse"
    }

    // Apps
    def createAppResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$appBody' --request POST https://${host}/developers/${developer[i]}/apps", returnStdout: true).trim()
    println "$createAppResponse"

    if (createAppResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** App ${appName[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createAppResponse.contains('409')) {
        def updateAppBody = """{
            "attributes": [{"name": "${appAttributeName[i]}", "value": "${appAttributeValue[i]}"}]
        }"""
        println "Updated App Body = $updateAppBody"

        def updateAppResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$updateAppBody' --request PUT https://${host}/developers/${developer[i]}/apps/${appName[i]}", returnStdout: true).trim()
        println "$updateAppResponse"
        if (updateAppResponse.contains('200')) {
            println "*** App ${appName[i]} updated successfully ***"
        } else {
            error "Failed to update ${appName[i]} with $updateAppResponse"
        }
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${appName[i]} with $createAppResponse"
    }
}

Folder Structure:

I run into errors at most of the lines while running migrateToGitHubActions.yaml
Do GitHub Actions have fewer scripting capabilities than Jenkins?
What kind of script is expected in Actions?
Error:

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
Illegal reflective access by
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
(file:/usr/share/groovy/lib/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method
java.lang.Object.finalize() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to
the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass WARNING:
Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal
reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations
will be denied in a future release Caught:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: json for
class: java.io.File groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such
property: json for class: java.io.File    at script.run(script.groovy:3)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)   at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


I run into errors at most of the lines while running migrateToGitHubActions.yaml. Could you share those errors in your question please?

The error seems related to the Config.json file. Could you share the whole repository structure in the question as well? It could be related to the file path. The more context shared in the question, the better :)

Sorry, I hope you have better understanding of my problem now.

Hmmm, in that case, the script and the groovy files are inside the github-actions directory. Therefore, given the context, I understand you'll need to enter this directory before running the script, something like this: run: cd github-actions && groovy script.groovy. This is necessary as the actions/checkout just clone the repository. You can also use the $GITHUB_WORKSPACE context variable to access your repo files.

Step List files (Start) shows that I'm in the write directory.
Run ls Config.json script.groovy
But, I still tried cd github-actions && groovy script.groovy
Result as expected: Run cd github-actions && groovy script.groovy /runner/_work/_temp/ae62580f-e195-43df-b008-ddb76f19f8d1.sh: line 1: cd: github-actions: No such file or directory Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
To prove that I'm in the right directory, I have added a println statement after #!groovy. - This worked:
*** Before Read *** Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such ...

Ok, you didn't need the cd command in that case, my bad. The problem seems related to the groovy script file, not with the github actions configurations. But as I'm not familiar with groovy, I don't really know how to resolve the issue. I'll make some tests here to check if I can get somewhere.

I asked chat GPT to correct the groovy script and got the workflow to work here by using this workflow file, and this updated groovy script.

To me, you're still a pro! :)
I was able to correct my script.groovy , but I am unable to fire a cURL request from script.groovy:
def createAppResponse = sh(script: "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$appBody' --request POST https://${host}/v1/organizations/rohit/developers/${developer[i]}/apps", returnStdout: true).trim()
Error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script.sh() 

Could you update the groovy script in the question with this curl request?

script.groovy is updated with the full code.

I checked here and it seems the sh commands is only available on Jenkins, you should replace this command line by execute in the groovy script, it should then work when running the workflow (this execute command should be executable after installing groovy).

Can I bother you to share the working code? I tried multiple methods, but haven't been successfully. To begin with, I'm focused only on the first curl request //Products. I have slightly changed the code by adding two new variables outpt and error :

// Products     def output = new StringBuffer()     def error = new StringBuffer()     def createProductResponse = ("curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $APIGEEDEVFUNCTIONALUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request POST https://${host}/apiproducts").execute().waitForProcessOutput(output, error)
Output: `*** createProductResponse = null ***
createProductResponseoutput = '
000''
000''
...
000'
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method contains() on null object
at (script.groovy:115)`

It seems we resolved the GitHub Actions / pipeline issue at least, now to focus on this other issue, it might be worth creating a new question on StackOverflow with the groovy tag asking feedback to this community. What do you think?

Would you like to add an official answer to this?

I've tested your workflow configuration and the issue you are facing seems related to the groovy script.
After a few researches (and Chat GPT usage) I identified that some command lines you are using with Jenkins aren't available on Github Actions directly.
Example: the sh commands is only available on Jenkins, you should replace this command line by execute in your groovy script, this operation should then work when running the script in the workflow.
Moreover, I asked chat GPT to correct the first version of the groovy script you shared (I'm not familiar with groovy) and got the workflow to work here by using this workflow file - updating some actions versions - and this updated groovy script.

Note: If you face more issues with the groovy script, I suggest asking another question on StackOverflow with the groovy tag, for the groovy community to give a more detailed answer.
